# Python - Distance matrix between geographic coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe panda with over 600 geographic coordinate points. An extract from him follows below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians

lat_long = pd.DataFrame({'LATITUDE':[-22.98, -22.97, -22.92, -22.87, -22.89], 'LONGITUDE': [-43.19, -43.39, -43.24, -43.28, -43.67]})
lat_long
```

To calculate the distance between two points manually, I use the code below:

```
lat1 = radians(lat_long['LATITUDE'][0])
lon1 = radians(lat_long['LONGITUDE'][0])
lat2 = radians(lat_long['LATITUDE'][1])
lon2 = radians(lat_long['LONGITUDE'][1])

R = 6373.0

dlon = lon2 - lon1
dlat = lat2 - lat1

a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

distance = R * c

print("Result:", round(distance,4))
```

What I need to do is create a function that uses the formula above to calculate the distance from all points to all, as in an array. But I have trouble thinking about what function to do and store the distances between the points. Every help is welcome. Output example (For illustrative purposes only, if I have not been clear):

```
|       |point 0 | point1 | point2 |
|point0 |    0   |    2   |   3    |
|point1 |    2   |    0   |   4    |
|point2 |    3   |    4   |   0    |
        |distance|distance|distance|
```

Comment: The formula above calculates the distance between points 0 and 1. if you wanted to generalize to points x and y, what would you do?

Comment: Actually, my difficulty is how and which data structure to store at a distance (dataframe, series, list, etc ...)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with a list of lists, so that `distances[n][m]` represents the distance between the n-th and m-th points.

Comment: if you have a distance function dist(x,y) which returns the distance between points x and y, [[dist(x,y) for x in points] for y in points]  is a pretty concise and readable way of generating such a matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [pdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) to compute the pairwise distances:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians

from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

lat_long = pd.DataFrame({'LATITUDE': [-22.98, -22.97, -22.92, -22.87, -22.89], 'LONGITUDE': [-43.19, -43.39, -43.24, -43.28, -43.67]})


def dist(x, y):
    """Function to compute the distance between two points x, y"""

    lat1 = radians(x[0])
    lon1 = radians(x[1])
    lat2 = radians(y[0])
    lon2 = radians(y[1])

    R = 6373.0

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = sin(dlat / 2) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2) ** 2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

    distance = R * c

    return round(distance, 4)


distances = pdist(lat_long.values, metric=dist)

points = [f'point_{i}' for i in range(1, len(lat_long) + 1)]

result = pd.DataFrame(squareform(distances), columns=points, index=points)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
         point_1  point_2  point_3  point_4  point_5
point_1   0.0000  20.5115   8.4123  15.3203  50.1784
point_2  20.5115   0.0000  16.3400  15.8341  30.0319
point_3   8.4123  16.3400   0.0000   6.9086  44.1838
point_4  15.3203  15.8341   6.9086   0.0000  40.0284
point_5  50.1784  30.0319  44.1838  40.0284   0.0000
```

Notice that `squareform` converts from a sparse matrix to a dense one, so the results are store in a numpy array.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution is

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians

lat_long = pd.DataFrame({'LATITUDE':[-22.98, -22.97, -22.92, -22.87, -22.89], 'LONGITUDE': [-43.19, -43.39, -43.24, -43.28, -43.67]})
lat_long

test = lat_long.iloc[2:,:]

def distance(city1, city2):
    lat1 = radians(city1['LATITUDE'])
    lon1 = radians(city1['LONGITUDE'])
    lat2 = radians(city2['LATITUDE'])
    lon2 = radians(city2['LONGITUDE'])

    R = 6373.0

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

    distance = R * c

    return distance

dist = np.zeros([lat_long.shape[0],lat_long.shape[0]])
for i1, city1 in lat_long.iterrows():
    for i2, city2 in lat_long.iloc[i1+1:,:].iterrows():
        dist[i1,i2] = distance(city1, city2)

print(dist)
```

**Output**

```
[[ 0.         20.51149047  8.41230771 15.32026132 50.17836849]
 [ 0.          0.         16.33997119 15.83407186 30.03192954]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          6.90864606 44.18376436]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.         40.02842872]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]
```

The lower triangle of the distance matrix is empty since that the matrix is symmetric (`dist[i1,i2]==dist[i2,i1]`)

Comment: Hello , thank you for the answer. I have a question. The results units are in km ?

Comment: It is since the earth radius has been expressed in km (`R = 6373.0`). If you prefer the result in miles for example, you could express R in miles ('R = 3,958.8')

Answer (score 0):

Using [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/):

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

lat_long = pd.DataFrame({'LATITUDE':[-22.98, -22.97, -22.92, -22.87, -22.89], 'LONGITUDE': [-43.19, -43.39, -43.24, -43.28, -43.67]})

# Convert Pandas dataframe to GeoPandas dataframe
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    lat_long,
    geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(lat_long['LONGITUDE'], lat_long['LATITUDE']),
    crs='EPSG:4326' # Or change to what's appropriate for you.
)

# Calculate distances between points
distances = []
for _, row in gdf.iterrows():
    distances.append(gdf['geometry'].distance(row['geometry'])*100)

# Create data frame of distances
distances_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(distances)
print(distances_df)
```

Output:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.000000 | 20.024984 | 7.810250 | 14.212670 | 48.836462 |
| 1 | 20.024984 | 0.000000 | 15.811388 | 14.866069 | 29.120440 |
| 2 | 7.810250 | 15.811388 | 0.000000 | 6.403124 | 43.104524 |
| 3 | 14.212670 | 14.866069 | 6.403124 | 0.000000 | 39.051248 |
| 4 | 48.836462 | 29.120440 | 43.104524 | 39.051248 | 0.000000 |

Note that this output is likely different from other answers because of the Coordinate Reference System (CRS). Find the appropriate CRS for you [here](https://epsg.io).